# Creating table from multidimention array

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional arrays with which I need to make a table in html. I have a problem with matching catalog numbers with dates in the table.

I created an array (little part of it below):

array cotains  date => CatalogNo => [catalogNo],[count],[date]

```
Array
(
[2019/07/19] => Array
    (

        [71156] => Array
            (
                [catalogNo] => 71156
                [count] => 22
                [date] => 2019/07/19
            )

        [71157] => Array
            (
                [catalogNo] => 71157
                [count] => 21
                [date] => 2019/07/19
            )

        [71221] => Array
            (
                [catalogNo] => 71221
                [count] => 217
                [date] => 2019/07/19
            )
)

[2019/07/18] => Array
    (
        [71156] => Array
            (
                [catalogNo] => 71156
                [count] => 26
                [date] => 2019/07/18
            )

        [71157] => Array
            (
                [catalogNo] => 71157
                [count] => 25
                [date] => 2019/07/19
            )

        [71221] => Array
            (
                [catalogNo] => 71221
                [count] => 281
                [date] => 2019/07/19
            )

        [71222] => Array
            (
                [catalogNo] => 71221
                [count] => 173
                [date] => 2019/07/19
            )
 ...
```

I did something like this but this is just bad. I dont know how to do it actually.

`$dane_arr`  <- this is the whole array

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>CatalogNo</th>
    <?php
    foreach( $dane_arr as $k => $v )
    {
        ?>
        <th><?php echo $k ?></th>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</tr>
<?php
foreach( $dane_arr as $k_date => $date_ )
{
    foreach( $date_ as $k_nrArt_ => $nrArt_ )
    { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $nrArt_['catalogNo'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $nrArt_['count'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

`

There are duplicates in CatalogNo and of course dates doesn't fit.

I want to create table, something like that:

`CatalogNo  |  2019/07/18 |  2019/07/19  |   ...
71156             26            22          ... 
71157             25            21          ...
71221             281           217         ...
71222             173           0           ...`

(Of course without duplicates in 'CatalogNo')

Comment: I would first make sure the array you start with makes sense. It doesn't need to be: `date => catalogNo => [catalogNo],[count],[date]`, it could just be: `date => catalogNo => count`. Much simpler and no duplication of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would first need to rearrange your array. Then you get all dates, and create the table:

```
<?php

$catalogUsage = [];
foreach ($dane_arr as $date => $catalogs) {
    foreach( $catalogs as $catalogNo => $catalog) {
         $catalogUsage[$catalogNo][$date] = $catalog['count'];
    }
}

$allDates = array_keys($dane_arr);

?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>CatalogNo</th>
    <?php

    foreach ($allDates as $date) {
        echo "<th>$date</th>"
    }

    ?>
</tr>
<?php

foreach($catalogUsage as $catalogNo => $counts)
{
    echo "<tr><td>$catalogNo</td>";
    foreach ($allDates as $date) {
        echo "<td>" . (isset($counts[$date]) ? $counts[$date] : 0) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
</table>
```

Code is untested, since I haven't got the original array, so bugs might exist. I just hope this gives you some new inspiration.

Comment: I added a few corrections and the code started to work as it should :) thank you!